# Not able to declare a function in the console when brackets on the same line

Tags: javascript

In the Chrome console, I executed the following function:

```
function getData_working(){ 
  return [
    {Category: "Category 1", Key: "Key 10", Value: 1},
    {Category: "Category 2", Key: "Key 10", Value: 1}
  ];
}
```

It does work and executing `getData_working()` afterwards produces the expected array with two objects. However, when I execute the following function (and I've actually copied the former, only changing the placement of the brackets, to make sure it isn't a typo), I get `undefined`.

```
function getData2_failing(){ 
  return 
    [{Category: "Category 1", Key: "Key 10", Value: 1},
    {Category: "Category 2", Key: "Key 10", Value: 1}];
}
```

What's happening here? How does someone explain this "bug" or "feature"?

Comment: 3 words: Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

Comment: @elclanrs In response to that I have 2 words. But I'm not supposed to spell them out. :)

Comment: @Xufox I'm not sure if you realize but coming up with **that** search query requires a state of insanity allowing one to even consider such a thing. It's absolutely contra-intuitive and not feasible to come up with. I regard it as a bug of the language. It's probably documented somewhere but I don't care. It's a bug. And a insane, such...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put `return` on its own line. Well, you can, but if you do, you will get a return value of `undefined` every time. This is because of how [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html) works.

> - **Forbidden LineTerminators:** The following syntactic constructs forbid a newline (“LineTerminator”) at a certain position. If there is a newline at that position, a semicolon is inserted. The ECMAScript standard calls the grammar rules below *restricted productions*.
>
> **PostfixExpression**
>   LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] `++`
>   LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] `--`
>
> **ContinueStatement**
>   `continue` [no LineTerminator here] Identifier? ;
>
> **BreakStatement**
>   `break` [no LineTerminator here] Identifier? ;
>
> **ReturnStatement**
>   `return` [no LineTerminator here] Expression? ;
>
> **ThrowStatement**
>   `throw` [no LineTerminator here] Expression? ;
>
> For PostfixExpression, the rationale is avoiding the modification of a value on the previous line. For continue, break, **return** and throw, the rationale is that if they are used without an argument, they should not refer to the next line if one forgets a semicolon.
>
> <sub>source: http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html</sub>

If you want the brackets on the next line, you need

```
return (
  [ ... ]
);
```

Or do like you've done in your original code

```
return [
  ...
];
```

Comment: The person responsible for that should be shot three times in the left foot and made write the sign of semicolon in their own blood for the rest of eternity and then more.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Remember, the core of JavaScript was written in 10 days :)

Comment: @Konrad, there are many more offensive aspects of JavaScript. See also: gcampbell's comment ^_^

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I'm not sure why you think this is a bad thing. It is a language feature, not a deficiency. Go has this too btw.

Comment: @elclanrs It's contra-intuitive. It doesn't serve any apparent purpose. It's hard to trouble-shoot unless known to the developer. In fact, I'm familiar with the automatic semicolon insertion from before. Still, I got stuck on this. Might be my opinion (only shared with my network peers) but I'm kind of certain that most people get confused by this.

Comment: @KonradViltersten if you read the 2ality article, there's a rationale provided; tho you may disagree with it. I've copied it to this answer as well.

Comment: @gcampbell There are other things people have done in 10 days that call for the capital punishment... (Of course, I'm kidding, fueled by fury and frustration but kidding. In fact, I do like JS. Mostly.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten *"It's hard to trouble-shoot unless known to the developer."* - well the [developer is responsible for knowing the tools he/she works with](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding). *"In fact, I'm familiar with the automatic semicolon insertion from before"* - well apparently not familiar enough :(

Comment: @naomik You're absolutely right. It's my ignorance of the ASI that got me here. Pure frustration. Too much C# lately, hehe.

Comment: @KonradViltersten consider this statement `if (y===0) \n return \n else \n return x/y`. Here `return` is used more like an early exit of the function. It's not a particularly useful example (I'd never write a function like this) but it might be a possibility the creators were thinking of when making this rule